# How many ways are there to express 24 as the sum of 4 2's and 16 1's where the order counts and there are never successive 2's?

Tags: combinatorics

I'm having trouble making sure order counts and that there are never successive 2's.

Comment: You should show something of what you've tried.

Answer (score 1):

We have to decide **where** to place the four $2$'s.

Line up the sixteen $1$'s in a row, with a little space between each of them.

They determine $17$ "gaps" (we include the endgaps).

We have to **choose** $4$ gaps from the $17$ available to slip a $2$ into.